# Matlab Extracting sub string from cell array

Tags: regex, matlab

I have a '3 x 1' cell array the contents of which appear like the following:

```
'ASDF_LE_NEWYORK Fixedafdfgd_ML'
'Majo_LE_WASHINGTON FixedMonuts_ML'
'Array_LE_dfgrt_fdhyuj_BERLIN Potato Price'
```

I want to be able to elegantly extract and create another '3x1' cell array with contents as:

```
'NEWYORK'
'WASHINGTON'
'BERLIN'
```

If you notice in above the NAME's are after the last underscore and before the first SPACE or '_ML'. How do I write such code in a concise manner.

Thanks

Edit:

Sorry guys I should have used a better example. I have it corrected now.

Comment: The names *aren't* after the last underscore, at least not in the first two entries.

Comment: I updated my answer to get the output in the format you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use lookbehind for `_` and lookahead for space:

```
names = regexp(A, '(?<=_)[^\s_]*(?=\s)', 'match', 'once');
```

Where `A` is the cell array containing the strings:

```
A = {...
'ASDF_LE_NEWYORK Fixedafdfgd_ML'
'Majo_LE_WASHINGTON FixedMonuts_ML'
'Array_LE_dfgrt_fdhyuj_BERLIN Potato Price'};

>> names = regexp(A, '(?<=_)[^\s_]*(?=\s)', 'match', 'once')
names = 
    'NEWYORK'
    'WASHINGTON'
    'BERLIN'
```

Comment: It works. But can you please explain how to read this: '(?<=_)[^\s_]*(?=\s)' ?

Comment: `(?<=_)` looks for a `_` before the matching string but doesn't include it in the match and `(?=\s)` looks for a space after matching string and doesn't include it in the match and the matching string is `[^\s_]*` meaning a sequence of non-space, non-underscore characters. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html for more info

Answer (score 1):

*NOTE*: The question was changed, so the answer is no longer complete, but hopefully the `regexp` example is still useful.

Try `regexp` like this:

```
names = regexp(fullNamesCell,'_(NAME\d?)\s','tokens');
names = cellfun(@(x)(x{1}),names)
```

In the pattern `_(NAME\d?)\s`, the parenthesis define a subexpression, which will be returned as a token (a portion of matched text).  The `\d?` specifies zero or one digits, but you could use `\d{1}` for exactly one digit or `\d{1,3}` if you expect between 1 and 3 digits.  The `\s` specified whitespace.

The reorganization of `names` is a little convoluted, but when you use regexp with a cell input and `tokens` you get a cell of cells that needs some reformatting for your purposes.